# select data from datetime according to date and time MATLAB

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have a datetime Array:

'2020-01-02 13:00:00'
'2020-01-02 13:01:00'
'2020-01-02 13:02:00'
'2020-01-02 13:03:00'
'2020-01-02 13:04:00'
...
'2020-01-02 23:59:00'

I want to select records between 14:30 to 21:00 for each day.
I have this:

idx_time = (Data.Timestamps.Hour >= 14 & Data.Timestamps.Minute >= 30) & (Data.Timestamps.Hour < 21);

but all the values from minute 00 to 30 are lost.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried to make the two dates in a datetime format ? Like this

```
d1 = '2020-01-02 14:30:00';
d2 = '2020-01-02 21:00:00';
t1 = datetime(d1,'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
t2 = datetime(d2,'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
idx_time = (Data >= t1) & (Data <= t2);
```

Comment: Thanks. Did not try that because it's one full year, This would workably for that day in question.

Comment: You can build t1 and t2 MATLAB formated date for any time and date you need ...

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out one way.
I got stuck trying to get a direct solution.

An added block solves it quite simply. May not be the best/elegant solution but it seems to work. I'll leave it here as it may be helpful for someone else.

idx_time = (Data.Timestamps.Hour >= 14 & Data.Timestamps.Minute >= 30 & Data.Timestamps.Hour < 21) | (Data.Timestamps.Hour >= 15 & Data.Timestamps.Hour < 21);